# Given a nested object I need to read values and display output in array

Tags: javascript

Input -

```
{
    name: 'hi',
    rollNo: {
        id: 3,
        sub: {
            type: ['math','science']
        }
    }
    }
```

Output-`["hi",3,"math","science"]`

CODE i have written

```
var flattenObject = function(obj){
      for(var i in obj){
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(i))continue;
        if(typeof obj[i] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[i]) && obj[i] !== null){
        flattenObject(obj[i]);
        }
        if(Array.isArray(obj[i]) && obj[i] !== null){
          
           //handling array condition
        }
        result.push(obj[i]);
        
      }
      console.log("Array",result);
      return result;
    }
```

Any lead on this ,or may be there is any other way to approach?

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with the code you've written, specifically? And what have you done to try to debug those problems and resolve them?

Comment: 0: "hi"
1: 3
2: ["math"]
3: {type: Array(1)}
4: {id: 308, sub: {…}}  this is  the Output i am getting i understand the problem occurs when type encounters as array ,but i dont understand how to handle that push back again in result array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive `flatMap`.

```js
const o = {
  name: 'hi',
  rollNo: {
    id: 3,
    sub: {
      type: ['math', 'science']
    }
  }
};
const getEntries = (o, f) => {
  const obj = f ? o[1]: o;
  return obj === Object(obj) ? Object.entries(obj).flatMap(e => getEntries(e, true)) : [o];
}
console.log(getEntries(o));
```

Comment: Is there any chance i can get key also infront of every value?

Comment: @miranal Happy to help.

Comment: i have posted 1 more question can u check if u can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Object.values`, witch return values for all enumerable props, if specific value is object (works also for arrays but not nulls) you can recursively call the function. If you want to skip nulls/undefined add some `if`s with `continue`.

```js
function values(obj) {
    var v = Object.values(obj);
    var out = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        const element = v[i];
        if (element !== null && typeof element === 'object') {
            out = out.concat(values(element));
            continue;
        }
        out.push(element);
    }

    return out;
}
```

input:

```js
var xx = {
    name: 'hi',
    rollNo: {
        id: 3,
        sub: {
            type: ['math', 'science']
        },
        undef: undefined,
        nil: null,
        fal: false,
        ze: 0
    }
};
```

output:

```js
[ 'hi', 3, 'math', 'science', undefined, null, false, 0 ]
```